# What things to make sure before developing Facebook Apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I m developing the facebook app(game). Can any one tell me what thing to make sure before developing the facebook app. Like:

- Is we need to store access token for facebook app.
- How many permission we need for basic facebook app.

and anything else we have to do. i m confuse so i just want to clear before starting facebook app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to get a facebook developer account, you will get your accesstoken and app ID from there, that all that you need ,
i will advice you to have a good look at the [FacebbokDeveloperWebSite](https://developers.facebook.com/)

Hope this make sense

Regards